# python 3 project structure for single v.s. multiple modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a python project, I have the following directory structure

```
├── cooccurrence
│   ├── cooccurrence.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_coccurrence.py
```

This leads to tests code inside my test source files having a quite ceremonial line:

```
from cooccurrence.cooccurrence import CoCreate
```

How would I simplify this overall setup if I only needed a single module, and conversely, what project structure should I have to manage multiple modules under the same package?

To test, I simply use `python -m unittest discover -v`, and a solution that can also seamlessly enable using the project within PyCharm would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this case, I would just shorten the name of the package :)

Answer (score 2):

You can import files in `__init__.py` so it will be available on package level. For example you can do in `cooccurrence/__init__.py`:

```
from cooccurrence import CoCreate
```

and then in your test file:

```
from cooccurrence import CoCreate
```

It will be the Pythonic way of doing so

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code line in `cooccurrence/__init__.py` path:

```
from cooccurrence import *
```

---

[**Note**]:

Tested on *Python 2.7*